# Jenkins:Error: Could not find or load main class –jar

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins

I am running a selenium IDE Testcase on jenkins and i have downloaded selenium HQ plugin for jenkins and create a project in Jenkins to run my test case. I am getting the error

```
[seleniumIDETest] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson9142255229009628890.sh
+ java –jar /home/jenkins/software/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.43.1.jar -htmlSuite *firefox http://www.google.com /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/googleTest/googleTestSuite.html /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/googleTest/test.html 

Error: Could not find or load main class –jar
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Publishing Selenium report...
Finished: FAILURE
```

[image]

The above execute shell command works from command line but not from jenkins.
Any help will be appreciate

Comment: it is taking `–jar` as classname, is it a single `-`?

Comment: you probably copypasted some code from some blog... and it used `–` (U+2013 EN DASH) instead of `-` (hyphen) for `-jar`

Comment: The above execute shell command works well from command line but not from jenkins. I have also tried the above (U+2013 En DASH) instead of hyphen and i get the same error.Reference to this configuration is mentioned in   Seleniumhq plugin website https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Seleniumhq+Plugin